# Does Timer.periodic need to be cancelled on widget unmount?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I'm using flutter hooks, and using the Timer.periodic to do some processing in my widget.

Here's how I'm using it:

```
    final countdownStream = useMemoized(
      () => Timer.periodic(
        // ...
      ),
    );
```

Do I need to cancel this or will it automatically be removed? If I extract the Timer.periodic to a reusable function, what then?

Thanks

Comment: I believe useMemoized is automatically disposing of anything connected to the Timer, so it should be safe.